# How to insert a TAB character into the Java logger message?

Tags: java, jboss, formatting, log4j

My JBoss logger format string is:

```
<pattern-formatter pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p\t[%c] %s%E (%t)%n"/>
```

I found no formatter variable for a tab character and \t does not work. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use character entities in hex format:

```
tab = &#x9;

<pattern-formatter pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p&#x9;[%c] %s%E (%t)%n"/>
```

Technically, I think it should be

```
&#x09;
```

but JBoss changes it to

```
&#x9;
```

after launch.

http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/latin1.html